# subtract a constant from a column to create a new one

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a geodata frame. I have a column and I would like to create a new one subtracting one if that column is strictly greater than 0, otherwise,  maintain the same value.

I have tried the following:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda y: (df['old_column'].subtract(1)) if y['old_column'] > 0 else y['old_column'], axis=1)
```

It's doing well at the time to differentiate when `old_column` is greater than 0, but at the moment to substract one, it's doing something strange, it's not substracting, it's just given a series of numbers, 3-2 2-1 1 1-1, things like that. Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you need to take one cell and not the entire column df['old_column'] => y['old_column']. In addition, there is no subtract method for a numpy object.

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda y: (y['old_column'] - 1) if y['old_column'] > 0 else y['old_column'], axis=1)
```

A simpler expression if data from one column is used

```
df['new_column'] = df['old_column'].apply(lambda y: y - 1 if y > 0 else y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `apply` you can use `np.where` which is faster for bigger dataframes and easier to read.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"old_column": [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]})
df["new_column"] = np.where(df.old_column > 0, df.old_column-1, df.old_column)
```

df

```
   old_column  new_column
0          -3          -3
1          -2          -2
2          -1          -1
3           0           0
4           1           0
5           2           1
6           3           2
```

If this does not work for your df, please include an example